# Android make entire screen scroll to certain point when keyboard shows

Tags: android, xml, layout, xamarin

I have an android app with a login screen (screenshot 1) and the login screen has 3 main views: inputs for username and password and a login button. I want all three of them to be visible when keyboard is shown (scroll entire screen/view upwards) the rest can be moved out of screen or blocked by keyboard.

I have read most of the similar stack overflow posts about this, but most of them say to use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`, `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` or both and i have tried both of them and some combinations with `stateVisible`, but none work. The closest to the wanted result i got, was by using `adjustPan` (screenshot 2).

Layout for login screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/login_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/primary"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    <!--Language select-->
        <include
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            layout="@layout/lang_select" />
    <!--Text: "Sign in"-->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sign in"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:padding="24dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    <!--google+ register button-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/btn_google_login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            style="@style/MyTheme.Button.Red">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_google_plus"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:text="Sign in with Google+"
                android:textSize="16dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    <!--Divider ("OR")-->
        <include
            layout="@layout/divider" />
    <!--Form-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/login_username_input"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="84dp"
                android:padding="0dp"
                style="@style/MyTheme.TextInputLayout"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/MyTheme.TextInputLayout.Activated">
                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/username"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/login_password_input"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="84dp"
                android:padding="0dp"
                style="@style/MyTheme.TextInputLayout"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/MyTheme.TextInputLayout.Activated">
                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        <!--Login button-->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/btn_login"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                style="@style/MyTheme.Button.Empty">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_user_plus"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:text="Sign in"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        <!--"Forgot password"-->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/btn_forgot_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="@string/forgot_password"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
<!--"Register a new account"-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/btn_register_here"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="@string/register_here" />
<!--For using snackbar-->
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/login_coord_layout" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Screenshot 1:**
[image: Login screen]

**Screenshot 2:** Login screen with keyboard showing with `adjustPan`. The whole screen has moved up a bit so the password input would be above keyboard. I want to move the whole view up even more so that the login button would be visible no matter which text input field has focus.
[image: Login screen with keyboard]

Comment: Actually its pretty difficult to achieve. But a workaround that strikes my mind now is, listen for change in state on IME editor, if the IME editor is shown, then add the whole view inside a scroll view and make the height of the view to be 1/3rd of the screen. Will post the answer soon , id this helps.

Comment: What happens when you are using android:windowSoftInputMode =  "adjustResize"? I think it might solve your problem.

Comment: @PravinDivraniya Nothing, even the view in focus gets blocked by keyboard. Maybe it's because of my layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set your parent view to `scrollview` with `adjustPan` or `adjustResize` and try . though it will not display your whole view it will just scroll to dislay your focusable control.

```
<ScrollView>
<RelativeLayout>// and so on</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

hope this will help.

Comment: It already displays the focused control. If I click on username, it doesn't need to scroll, if I click on password, it scrolls a little bit so that password field is visible

Comment: Yea, i reviewed my unresolved questions and in this case, I achieved the desired result by using something similar to your answer (created a custom scrollview). Your answer had put me in the right direction.

Comment: it is fine as long as answer is helpful to you :) . happy coding

Answer (score 0):

try this in your Java code

```
       getActivity().getWindow()
            .setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as setting those properties in the manifest?